# Python: How to combine two SQL queries

Tags: python, sql

As I have limited knowledge about Python how can I crate in Python one query  which will contains both from below where second will be queried for when first will return not results (no email address returned)

Code blow

```
bits = sys.argv[1].split('@')
if len(bits) != 2:
    sys.exit(0)

cur.execute("SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE diraddr = %s", (sys.argv[1],))    
cur.execute("SELECT email FROM users WHERE (username LIKE %s) AND (domain LIKE %s) and notifications = 'Y'", (bits[0], bits[1]))
```

I have tried to do IF...ELSE for `email` return results from  first SQL query but it looks like can be done in one query without IF...ELSE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends -- what do you mean by "combine?" Do you mean concatenate row-wise? If so, you're looking for `UNION ALL`:

```
cur.execute("SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE diraddr = {0} UNION ALL SELECT email FROM users WHERE (username LIKE {1}) AND (domain LIKE {2}) and notifications = 'Y'".format(sys.argv[1], bits[0], bits[1]))
```

The `UNION ALL` operator combines the results from multiple queries, as long as they have the same number of columns. This will work even if one (or both) of the subqueries return no results.

> Note: I updated your code using [Python's .format() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: In fact, you should use cursor parameters instead. No format or modulus for literal values.

Comment: Great. That is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific with the question when you say COMBINE.

From what I understand from the code is that you will you be getting an email id as input (as argument)?

You will split that email id and store username and domain name as 2 list elements. If the first query do not return any result(querying notification table) , then you want to execute another query(on users table) using the element in the list?

If above scenario is true, then use a simple if else logic to check if the first query is returning any result.If it is not returning anything, then execute the 2nd query in the else part.

Comment: Exactly what I was doing but I was looking for to get it done at one shot (query).

Comment: Since the functionality is to execute based on an event (if-else), you have to write a if -else logic to get this done. 

or else 

use the UNION statement as mentioned in above answer.
NOTE: The above query has UNION ALL in it. This might retrieve more than 1 record in case the value exists in both the tables. So, use a UNION instead of UNION ALL to retrieve only UNIQUE record every time.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for your help!